# Number theoretic problems leading to elliptic curves

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am looking for basic number theoretic problems that can be addressed by the use of elliptic curves.
I know few of problems such as congruent number problem, or the problem of extending a Diophantine triple $\{a,b,c\}$ to a quadruple $\{a,b,c,x\} $satisfying $ax+1 = \square, ~bx+1 = \square, ~cx+1 = \square,$ where a Diophantine triple is set consisting three integers with the property that product of any two increased by one is always a perfect square e.g. $\{1,3,8\}$ and $\square$ denotes perfect square. This problem can be addressed by the elliptic curve $E: y^2 = (ax+1)(bx+1)(cx+1).$ I am looking for some more problems that can have relations with elliptic curve. What are those problems and what can be a source to understand them?

Comment: Maybe look up “congruent numbers”?

Comment: Here's a paper of which I'm a co-author which solves an elementary problem using elliptic curves:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06681v1

Comment: thank you @Goddard

Answer (score 3):

Um, all of them? (That's an exaggeration, but only slightly.)

For example consider the $n=3$ case of Fermat's Last Theorem. You're looking for nontrivial integer solutions to $a^3 + b^3 = c^3$. Dividing by $c^3$ and setting $x = a/c$ and $y = b/c$, we get the new equation $x^3 + y^3 = 1$, where now we are looking for rational solutions instead of integer solutions (since if $a,b,c$ are integers then $x,y$ are rational numbers, and vice-versa). If you know enough general theory, you may recognize that $x^3+y^3 = 1$ is an elliptic curve. Explicitly, if we set $C : x^3 + y^3 = 1$ and $E : Y^2 - 9Y = X^3 - 27$, then the transformation
\begin{align*}
X &= \frac{3 y}{1-x} \\
Y &= \frac{9 x}{x-1}
\end{align*}
maps $C$ to $E$, and the inverse transformation is
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{Y}{Y - 9} \\
y &= \frac{3 X}{9 - Y}
\end{align*}

mapping $E$ to $C$. Hence by finding rational points on the elliptic curve $E$, we can find rational points on $C$, and vice-versa. To find rational points on $E$, we can use the general theory of elliptic curves. For example, as told by [Sagemath](https://sagemath.org/):

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve([0,0,-9,0,-27])
sage: E.rank()
0
sage: E.torsion_points()
[(0 : 1 : 0), (3 : 0 : 1), (3 : 9 : 1)]
```

This computation indicates that $\{\mathcal{O}, (3,0), (3,9)\}$ are the only rational points on $E$. Translating back to $C$ using the above equations, we find that $(x,y) = (1,0)$ and $(x,y) = (0,1)$ are the only rational points on $C$. So that's how you prove one of the cases of Fermat's Last Theorem using the general theory of elliptic curves.

A similar trick works with the $n=4$ case. If $a^4 + b^4 = c^2$, then divide by $b^4$ and substitute $x = a/b$ and $y = c/b^2$ to obtain $C : x^4 + 1 = y^2$. Then $C$ is an elliptic curve, birational to $E : Y^2 = X^3 - 4X$, with equations
\begin{align*}
X &= \frac{2x(y+1)}{x^3} \\
Y &= \frac{4(y+1)}{x^3} \\
x &= \frac{2X}{Y} \\
y &= \frac{2X^3-Y^2}{Y^2}
\end{align*}
mapping $C$ to $E$ and vice-versa. The only rational points on $E$ are $\{\mathcal{O}, (0,0), (\pm 2,0)\}$, from which one can deduce that $a^4+b^4=c^2$ has no nontrivial integer solutions.

Unfortunately, the elliptic curve train ends here. The $n=5$ and higher cases of Fermat's Last Theorem are not amenable to elementary elliptic curve manipulations (not counting Wiles' proof here, which of course **is** based on elliptic curves, but uses very advanced theory).

Comment: Thank you, I came across this in a textbook on elliptic curve by Washington L. C., I was looking for some other problems.

Comment: The $k=4$ case of Euler's generalization of Fermat's Last Theorem reduces to elliptic curves, as shown by Elkies and explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture#Counterexamples